# Disable Sign Up for ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'd like to disable sign up for ActiveAdmin and not just removing the link the Sign In page. Can that be done? Thanks

Comment: In the `AdminUser` model try removing the `:registerable` from devise. You may also disable the routes: `devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config.merge(skip: [:confirmations, :registrations])`

Comment: I'm hoping to disable it only for ActiveAdmin